# What .NET Framework do I use to create a board game?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I'd like to use .NET to create a board game.

1. I plan to implement a basic board game (something similar to chess, but less complicated) as graduate AI term project.
2. The GUI is not very important (it does not have to be easy to use, intuitive, animated etc), but if it doesn't add too much complication, then I want to add a better GUI.
3. The main objective is to submit as a term project, but I want to share it with the community so that others can also play. Deployment should make it easy to share the game with Windows workstations.

What framework do you guys suggest for such a project? I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325278/best-way-to-display-program-game-board) topic,  but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: game development is a whole other beast, maybe you should visit http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm more interested in Framework part, and I'm NOT going to dig into advanced topics of game development. :) I decided to keep this area as far as possible from my career, after a little experience with OpenGL game development :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making a board game like chess, and you don't really care to use this as a piece in a game programming portfolio, then I'd recommend you simply use a Windows UI framework, like WPF.  It is very easy to plug into eventing on such a system, and you'll get to use the integrated UI layout designer in Visual Studio.  Just make a grid of buttons (using images for their content)/other controls.  This will allow you to spend a ton less time on how it looks, and graphics/UI-related programming tasks, and quickly get you to programming the game logic.

If you are using this project for a game programming portfolio, I agree with George - use XNA.  If you do this, enlist an artist friend to take care of the UI design and graphical content for you (but not the graphical programming, of course).

You can also have the best of both worlds.  You can make your game logic UI-agnostic, and program a better UI later.  Postal chess is proof of this.

Comment: Do you think that WPF is kind of replacement of WinForms? In your opinion Wwich one is better for my case? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @just_azho: If you're going to learn one of them from scratch, and you already have a somewhat newer version of Visual Studio, then learn WPF.  Otherwise, they should be just about identical for your usage, so it doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 5):

If you said that the GUI is not important for now **then you do not need any game framework** which will only slow down you in making your game. 
Windows forms is more than  enough for you.

You should focus on implementing your game engine assembly. This assembly should have an open communication protocol and should NOT be aware of any GUI. In other words, you should decouple your engine from the GUI.

Later, you and others could create a GUI in theirs language of choice which will be using  your protocol to communicate and display the position of your game.

Good luck!

Comment: +1, a properly decoupled design is far more important than deciding on how the game will be visualized.

Comment: Problem #1: Getting it Working. All the design in the world doesn't help you if you can't ship.

Comment: I really don't know why you downvoted my answer George. I did not mention anything about design (apart from basic principles), perhaps you should read more carefully my answer. I suggest to implement engine, rather than focusing of picking up a framework when you do not have anything which is working.

Comment: 2 Things: You can only assume I downvoted your answer, there's no way to know for sure whether or not it was me or someone else. Also, asking him to start out by "Using an open Communication Protocol" and "Decouple [the] engine from the GUI" is a bit advanced for "Hey, I'm just getting into game programming." He's got a lot of problems to solve before you go all Architecture Astronaut on him.  Nevermind talking about YAGNI. Get the software running, then worry about those design considerations -- especially if it's your first time.

Comment: First thing, it's obvious that it was you Second thing, writing an open communication protocol is far more easier than learning the GUI framework *before actualy implementing the AI engine*. So you have chosen harder lerning curve for him and he might be stuck trying for hours making a "pawn" transparent or wondering why the animation is not smooth or just name dozens of other problems relevant to frameworks. And where he will be with his AI engine on that time? Isn't that opposite to your "get the software running"?

Comment: What does an open communication protocol have to do with getting a board game running? *Zilch*. So already by not going down that path he'll be a lot farther along than by going down the open communication protocol path.

Comment: "Open communication protocol" is a very big term for something which resolves to writing string to standard output by using a WriteLine() method. I give you an example: WriteLine("PAWN X:5 Y:7"). Now, if this is for you harder than learning XNA framework for unexperienced user than... IMHO you are simply wrong. Every AI engine must have a posibillity for two-way communication with environment. Answering your question: It has everything to do with an AI engine which OP reffers to. Your suggestion that he should not do that is actually a very bad advice.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and answer. You made some assumptions about my knowledge, so felt that I need to clarify it: I graduated from Comp. ENG. and have 4 years of industry work experience (but mostly on Java/J2EE). Currently Acquiring M.SC. Recently, I got an offer from MS, so meanwhile I want to learn their (well may be from now "our") technology as well. So please feel free to mention "advanced" topics in the answer. But I'm new to .NET framework only, and know very little.

Comment: About the answer: I think it makes sense, if the learning curve for GUI is high, then I can just make just console game. Then later someone can add GUI using my convention (protocol). Thanks

Comment: @Wodzu having created games using XNA, I can tell you from experience that it doesn't slow you down in making games at all. If anything it streamlines the process.  Have you worked with XNA at all?

Comment: @George: Yes I did. Have you ever implemented AI engine for turn based strategy game?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something in .NET related to game development, your best way would be to use the [.NET XNA Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx).

As far as making the gameboard, you'll need to learn how to program video games; there's really no 'built in' drag-and-drop create-a-board-game framework.

Looks like someone has a tutorial on [how to create a 'board based' game](http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-board-based-puzzle-game-with-microsoft-xna-4) in XNA 4.0.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Use XNA for Game Development.  Also look at http://create.msdn.com for tips, downloads, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms is the easiest to use if you're just getting started.  That said, if your primary interest is in testing the logic, you might even start with a Console application and wait to develop the UI until you have a stable notion of how the game will function.  I wouldn't recommend XNA for your first pass.  If you really want to refine it into a polished game, you can always build an XNA interface on top of your logic later.

The key thing here is to design your application in such a way that the logic and the UI are decoupled.  If you do this properly, then you're free to use a range of different UIs, perhaps starting with a Console, working up to a 'debug' style WinForms app, with a crude interface designed for your consumption, then finally up to a more polished interface for others to play.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Since WPF is relatively new, it is unclear if Windows Forms will continue to be improved in future .NET releases". Do you think that WPF is kind of replacement of WinForms? Which one is better for my case?

Comment: @just_azho, WPF is extremely powerful, but it has a pretty significant learning curve.  That said, WinForms won't go away any time soon; if nothing else because of a large legacy code base.  If you're interested, by all means, work with WPF.  It's definitely worth learning and I'm sure you could pick it up if you have the time and motivation.  WPF will give you flexibility to expand and create a rich UI later and, if you port it to Silverlight (which is very similar to WPF) you can deploy the game on the web.  If you go that route, I recommend getting a version of Expression Blend, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I needed a board, I just created a two-dimensional array of user-controls, gave each user control a border, and had their paint method draw anything on the inside of the board.  You can have your board user control and your game piece user control be separate objects or the same object, depending on what you are doing.  This strategy will take only a few hours to do, and gives you a lot of power.  For example, it is easy to add features to recognize things like drag/drop, clicking, etc.

Another way to create a game board is to just use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).  That's really not the intended use of that class and the code for that will get a little bit ugly, but if you write a wrapper around it it probably won't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I created a Connect4 application that had a bit of AI and used a database backing to "learn" from its mistakes as my Senior project. Some tips of advice though:

- Don't over complicate things. Don't sit there writing up a whole framework to work for multiple gameboards or strange possible settings (such as adding a 3rd player to the mix).
- Using a good pattern and language will make things far easier to in testing and debugging (my favorite is WPF using MVVM).

Also, if you do decide to go the route of Connect4, here is how I setup my classes:

**C4Board.cs**

- I made it into an immutable object that represented the GameBoard state.
- `C4Board Insert(int col)` would return a new GameBoard or throw an custom exception if the column was full.
- I made it immutable to work with having a "history" List of game states in the view.

**GamePlayer.cs**
 - Enumeration (NULL, P1, P2)
 - Extension Methods that let you change from GamePlayer -> GamePiece

**GamePiece.cs**
 - Enumeration (EMPTY, BLACK, RED)
 - Extension Methods that let you change from GamePiece -> GamePlayer

**GameWinner.cs**
 - Enumeration (NONE, P1, P2, TIE)

It's a simple game with simple rules, easy to separate out your logic and add AI, etc. It's much better than trying to come up with a chess game or Go game etc.