# Best graphic class for game board

Tags: android, graphics

I'm creating my first Android game, and I am wondering which class will be the best to create game border.

My game is easy. I want to make a border which has for example 10 fields. If I press a button (button is independent of board), I want to change color of one selected field.

Is SurfaceView a good solution for this or maybe you can propose a better solution?

Comment: What have you tried? What was your research? **You** decide which is the easiest! As for the question itself, I suggest you should read [this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) in which I had to go through the trouble in fixing up mis-spellings, in future, please double check and search over on the right, such as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325278/best-way-to-display-program-game-board?rq=1) BTW if you say the game is easy, then why are you asking about it, there's no code sample, nothing, so its going to be voted to close as not constructive or not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't going to have a very high number of elements, particle effects, animations, etc. (i.e. a simple game), [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) is probably your best bet.

It's simple, reasonably fast (for simple things), and works well on multiple screens.

You can find the developer guide article [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).